# libisl.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

After I installed Qt with `*.run` I tested a simple program. I got the  error below. I should note that `g++` compiles my codes with no problem. For some reason `libisl.so.13` is not found by `cc1plus` although the library exists. Why is that?

**Qt error:**

```
error: /usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**ldd cc1plus:**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd95fb8000)
libisl.so.13 => /usr/local/lib64/libisl.so.13 (0x00007f670624e000)
libmpc.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpc.so.3 (0x00007f6706036000)
libmpfr.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.4 (0x00007f6705dd0000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f6705b59000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f670593b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6705631000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6705268000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055ed64275000)
```

**echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:**

```
:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/lib64
```

**g++ --version:**

```
g++ (GCC) 6.2.0
```

Comment: Why don't you use package in your package manager?)

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this could happen; here's my 50 cents:

Recently I tried running some examples from Unified Automation for some OPC/UA control systems. Their evaluation version was compiled on Debian Wheezy, and I was using Debian Stretch. Their evaluation comes with precompiled libraries; they do this to make sure that you won't be able to manipulate the source code and use their software as full version. Consequently, I had the exact same problem you're having with OpenSSL 1.0.0, where a precompiled library tried to find that. So, do you have any precompiled libraries trying to do the same with `libisl.so`?

Eventually I compiled OpenSSL 1.0.0, and linked it, and got tons of segmentation faults... it was a dead end! So, to resolve this issue, I created a [chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot) with Debian Wheezy to evaluate that software, and that worked like a charm.

Another possible cause of the problem is: Binary incompatibility of architecture. Are you sure you're calling a 64-bit program and using a 64-bit library?